# ByteArrayInputStream, SequenceInputStream, StringReader where to use

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, stringreader, bytearrayinputstream

There are too many java.io classes, for some of them i really dont understand when we need them, for example:

ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream

SequenceInputStream,

PushbackInputStream, PushbackReader

StringReader...

I mean some real-life usages

Can someone please explain...

Comment: https://github.com/search?l=java&q=ByteArrayInputStream&source=cc&type=Code

Comment: may i know what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that your question is too wide.

However it is possible to give a very basic overview of [`java.io` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html). It contains *interfaces* and *classes* for data input and output operations, such as reading bytes from file. There are only few basic interfaces / classes:

- `DataInput` / `ObjectInput` - readig Java primitives and objects
- `DataOutput` / `ObjectOutput` - writing Java primitives and objects
- `InputStream` - reading individual *bytes*
- `OutputStream` - writing individial *bytes*
- `Reader` - reading *character data*
- `Writer` - writing *character data*

There are other useful interfaces (like `Closeable`), but these are less significant.

---

It is best if you read the JavaDoc of these classes. Some examples:

1. It is pretty obvious that you would use `FileOutputStream` to write something into a file.
2. Character data is represented by bytes (defined by character encoding), so you can wrap any output stream using `OutputStreamWriter`.
3. You have `byte[]` and want to read from it just like from `InputStream`? Use `ByteArrayInputStream`.
4. You want to be able to return read bytes back to the reader (usually only a single pass-through is supported)? Wrap your reader with `PushbackReader`.
5. You have some `String` and want to read from it just like from `Reader`? Use `StringReader`.
6. ...

So if you need some specific stream/reader/writer, check `java.io` package, search the internet and ask a question on SO if needed.

---

Of course then there is [`java.nio` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html), which you should know about. But that is for a different topic.

Comment: what I actually wanted was...not use of them in general...some examples of their special uses......like I have just found that byte array input stream can be used for some reading chunk of data (may be image) from an URL or may be from database...

Comment: for SequenceInputStream I cant find a useful use

Comment: **Just read the JavaDoc**... it can concatenate multiple streams. Lets say you want to hand over a single input stream to some component, which should read two files... `new SequenceInputStream(new FileInputStream("fileA"), new FileInputStream("fileB"))`.